# How to convert a function that returns unique_ptr into raw pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Suppose there is a function in a legacy library that I want to use that requires a function pointer as an input

```
void LegacyFunction(int* (*func)(float, float), int a, float b);
```

but the problem is it is expecting the return value of the function to be an int raw pointer instead of an int unique_ptr, meaning I can only get it to compile if my function looks like

```
int* MyFunc(float a, float b);
```

in other words, if I modify MyFunc into

```
std::unique_ptr<int> MyFunc(float a, float b);
```

and pass it into the legacy library function like

```
LegacyFunction(MyFunc, 1, 2.0f);
```

there will be a compilation error. I know if the function is taking an usual int pointer there can be some workaround using the `get()` function like

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a;
LegacyFunctionRawPointer(a.get(), 1, 2.0f);
```

Is there a similar workaround for function pointer input? It will be a travesty if I have to replace the unique_ptr for MyFunc with raw pointer.

Comment: Is `MyFunc` a runtime value or is it known at the compile time?

Comment: Who owns the pointer?  Is legacy library the owner?  Does legacy library destroy the pointer?

Comment: A simple lambda function wrapper seems like it would work, but you'd have memory leaks if the legacy didn't free the memory returned in the same way it was allocated.

Comment: You could wrap `MyFunc` in a lambda.

Comment: @krzaq it's known at compile time

Comment: @Robinson legacy library will own it, it will use the returned pointer from `MyFunc` somewhere in the code and delete it

Comment: @user3667089 then feel free to use ShadowRanger's solution. I would've offered the same one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lambda function should work, e.g.:

```
LegacyFunction([](float a, float b) { return MyFunc(a, b).release(); }, 1, 2.0f);
```

but only if `LegacyFunction` will naturally delete/free the memory that `MyFunc` allocated with the appropriate operation (so if `MyFunc` used `new int`, `LegacyFunction` must use `delete retval;`; if it used `new int[x]`, it must use `delete[] retval;`).

[The `release` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) gets the contained pointer and relinquishes ownership, so you've explicitly given up `unique_ptr`'s protections; not a great idea if you can avoid it.